# Make a container for each selected checkbox in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox

How can I make a container for each selected checkbox?

[like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0WmY.jpg)

When a check box is selected, a container appears with its value inside

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-container',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='vue-container'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="jack">Jack</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="john">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="mike">Mike</label>
  <br>
  <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your code seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-container',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #66FF99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='vue-container'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="jack">Jack</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="john">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="mike">Mike</label>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <span>Checked names:</span>
    <li v-for="name in checkedNames" :key="name">
      {{ name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```